# Can a method return an object and a value?

Tags: methods, adobe, extendscript, adobe-premiere

I'm learning Adobes Premiere Pro API (ExtendScript).
In the documentation, is says that the method for a Sequence Object called Sequence.createSubsequence() "Returns 0 if successful".

However in the example code, they assign the method to a variable, does this not suggest the method actually returns an Object rather than an integer (in this case it's a Sequence object)?

New to coding so trying to understanding if there's something fundamental I don't get here, or whether this is in fact an error.

```
var newSeq = activeSequence.createSubsequence(ignoreMapping);
                newSeq.name = "myseqname";
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like that documentation is wrong. If I run the code in the debug console it does indeed return a Sequence object.

```
app.project.activeSequence.createSubsequence(true)
→ [object Sequence]
```

Comment: Thanks can confirm it is wrong, Adobe has acknowledged and rectified it.  Thank you